# wkhtmltopdf: show content on footer, for example page number

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I expected this command to show `1/1` at the bootom of the generated pdf but no... any idea?

```
wkhtmltopdf --footer-center [page]/[topage] www.google.com /tmp/foobar.pdf
```

Version: 0.12.2.4 on Linux

Comment: what happens? Only show '/' or show nothing?

Comment: @RafaelDantas shows nothing

Comment: For test purpose, use --header-center and see if working. (Try put double quote in attribute text)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this issue may be due to version 0.12.2.4 otherwise, this `--footer-center [page]/[topage]` command will be doing your work.

one more example i have checked that `substitutePdfVariables()` is called in body onload.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        function substitutePdfVariables() {

            function getParameterByName(name) {
                var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
                return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            }

            function substitute(name) {
                var value = getParameterByName(name);
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(name);

                for (var i = 0; elements && i < elements.length; i++) {
                    elements[i].textContent = value;
                }
            }

            ['frompage', 'topage', 'page', 'webpage', 'section', 'subsection', 'subsubsection']
                .forEach(function(param) {
                    substitute(param);
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="substitutePdfVariables()">
    <p>Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here [Docs](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html) You can find out more variables about header and footer.

Comment: Docs seems outdated...and guess regarding linux version seems similar to earlier answer.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal , I have rechanged the docs hyperlink. I think from this answer, user can get their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a stability issue but there has not been a stable release of the version `0.12.2.4` for `linux` (`debian` or `ubuntu`) but *just for the debugging purposes as mentioned* in their repositories [here](http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/).

Here is the working screen shot for the `version` and `0.12.4`

**Version `0.12.4`**[image: foobar1]

or you can add the page number by the *following snippet* to add the footer as mentioned [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)

```
  <html><head><script>
  function subst() {
    var vars={};
    var x=window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for (var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
    var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
    for (var i in x) {
      var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
      for (var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
    }
  }
  </script></head><body style="border:0; margin: 0;" onload="subst()">
  <table style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td class="section"></td>
      <td style="text-align:right">
        Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body></html>
```